# How do I make the cursor to go back to RichTextBox after clicking a button?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I have some style buttons programmed, and I desire that right after the user clicks on a button, the cursor appears right away where he/she was typing before clicking the button.
Also, I wish for the cursor to appear right at the RichTextBox when the program is launched (also, when the user clicks on that tab in my TabIndex.
Thanks!

Comment: Also, I'd like by default for my RichTextBox to have a specific font and size.

Comment: [Focus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.focus(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: One suggestion to you: try to focus on one problem at a time.

Comment: And [SelectionStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.selectionstart(v=vs.110).aspx) will get/set the caret position.

Comment: More or less totally unrelated: Set `HideSelection to false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Code would have been nice to work with but this should give you a hint:

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        richTextBox1.Focus();
        richTextBox1.Select(lastPosition, 0);
    }
```

The focus makes the cursor appear and the select sets the position where the cursor should appear.
You only have to set the variable lastPosition yourself

And to change the default font etc. use this 
[image]

Comment: Thanks! I knew that the font was changeable on the properties... but it is one of those things that you are blind to for some reason!

Comment: About the cursor, thanks a lot :) I just needed to use the DreamRead.Focus(); part, as I was want the cursor to be sent back where it was originally before clinking the button. Thanks a ton!